# Can you separate a list of strings in a Pandas column to individual strings per row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have checked online and on Stack Overflow and can't seem to get an answer for this. Assume I have a dataframe that looks as such:

```
   colA          colG
0     1  [a, b, c, d]
1     2        [c, d]
2     3        [e, f]
3     4        [g, h]
4     5        [i, j]
```

Is it possible to flatten `colG` such that I get each letter assigned to a new row, something like:

```
   colA          colG    colH
0     1  [a, b, c, d]      a
1     1  [a, b, c, d]      b
2     1  [a, b, c, d]      c
3     1  [a, b, c, d]      d
4     2  [c, d]            c
5     2  [c, d]            d
```

NB: The values for other columns other than the index remain consistent, with the aim of dropping the list of str column (`colG`) after the operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `df.explode('colG')`

Comment: Just gotta merge back to the original data frame, in case you want to keep the columns `colG` with the lists too.